# error while using regex_replace function from <tr1/regex>

Tags: c++, regex, gcc, tr1

```
#include <string>
#include <tr1/regex>

#include "TextProcessing.h"

const std::string URL_PATTERN("((http://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\\+.~#?&//=]+)");
const std::string REPLACEMENT("<a href=\"$&\"\">$&</a>");

std::string textprocessing::processLinks(const std::string & text)
{

    // essentially the same regex as in the previous example, but using a dynamic regex
    std::tr1::regex url(URL_PATTERN);

    // As in Perl, $& is a reference to the sub-string that matched the regex
    return std::tr1::regex_replace(text, url, REPLACEMENT);
}
```

I'm using mingw gcc copiler 4.5.0 version.

I've got the follow error:

```
%DEV%> mingw32-make all
g++  -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wall -Wextra -std=c++0x -pedantic -Werror -c  -I./include TextProcessing.cpp
cc1plus.exe: warnings being treated as errors
c:\dev\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/tr1_impl/regex:2390:5: error: inline function '_Out_iter std::tr1::regex_replace(_Out_iter, _Bi_iter, _Bi_iter, const std::tr1::basic_regex<_Ch_type, _Rx_traits>&, const std::basic_string<_Ch_type>&, std::tr1::regex_constants::match_flag_type) [with _Out_iter = std::back_insert_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >, _Bi_iter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >, _Rx_traits = std::tr1::regex_traits<char>, _Ch_type = char, std::tr1::regex_constants::match_flag_type = std::bitset<11u>]' used but never defined
mingw32-make: *** [TextProcessing.o] Error 1
Process mingw32-make exited with code 2
```

Comment: Duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860722/linker-error-when-using-tr1regex and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398994/link-tr1-on-ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, in my g++ include files I also see that `regex_replace` is declared and not defined.  For me, it's in the file /usr/include/c++/4.4.4/tr1_impl/regex .  Just above the declaration is a Doxygen comment section which includes:

```
/** @todo Implement this function. */
```

Answer (score 1):

Your standard C++ library does not have complete c++0x (now c++1x?) support. Try using Boost's code. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860722/linker-error-when-using-tr1regex#answer-2860869).